# Amazon AWS RDS provisioned storage cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am currently using a free tier AWS RDS and I set it up with `15,000 GiB storage` and a `16,000 Maximum storage threshold`, and the `Multi-AZ` left unchecked tho.

I just want to confirm if is this what makes the cost so expensive?

Hoping someone answers me with this one coz I'm pretty hecked about this one.

Here's the breakdown:

[image]

Comment: It could be. Why did you provision the DB with so much storage?

Comment: @jellycsc its my first time with cloud services and I really thought having that much storage is free as long as I am using free tier instance

Comment: Unfortunately, only the instance itself is free. Please open a support ticket ASAP and explain the situation to them. They might be able to give you a refund.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you provisioned quite some storage, especially as it seems you are not using this for a production workload.

Only 20 GB of General Purpose (SSD) DB Storage is included in the free tier. Have a look here: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/

Best, Stefan